# How to redirect a `RustRun` out to a split buffer in vim

Tags: vim, rust, vim-plugin, neovim

When running RustRun in vim with [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim), it will print its output to the vim command output console. Whereas running `go-run` for the Go program it will open a new terminal split and print outputs there.

1. How do I run the Rust program in a new split buffer?
2. How do I reuse the same buffer every time call rust run?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I used `Redir` to redirect the command output to a new split window.
To reuse the same buffer, create a new named buffer, and write output to it. When calling rust run find the named buffer and delete if exist.

```
function! Redir(cmd)
    redir => output
        silent! execute(a:cmd )
    redir END
    let output = split(output, "\n")
    
    if bufwinnr('rust.out') >0 
       bdelete rust.out
    endif

    vnew rust.out
    let w:scratch = 1
    setlocal buftype=nofile filetype=rust_out bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
    call setline(1, output)

    "focus back to the source file on the left, from which we ran `RustRun`
    wincmd h
endfunction

"redirect any vim command output using Redir command.
command! -nargs=1 Redir call Redir(<f-args>)

"mapping for rust files.
au FileType rust nmap <silent> <leader>rr  :call Redir('RustRun')<CR><CR>
```